# Wordpress doesn`t show background photo of <p> element in my theme

Tags: wordpress

I have been trying to make a wordpress theme and wanted it to be nicer. I have added a background image in "style" property, but Wordpress does not show it.
Here is my code:

```
<p align='center' id='intro' style='align-content:center center; 
    font- size:5vh;padding-top:40vh;height:100vh; width:100vw; color:white;
    font-family:"Times New Roman"; background-attachment:fixed;
    background-image: url("images/jazz_lounge_intro.jpg");
    background-color: #cccccc; background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed; background-size:cover;'>
    Lorem Ipsum 
</p>
```

Comment: Could you use `Background Image` and `Background Color` together?

Comment: most ikey that filepath for the background-image doesn't work. In Wordpress it's common practice to use absolute filepaths, so I would try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Johannes has commented.

Set the full path to the image:

```
background-image: url("http://example.com/.../.../images/jazz_lounge_intro.jpg");
```